# Sidebar menu with multiple action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

First of all : Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqdmny41/9/) . there is a button top of the menu and there is a sidebar menu with 4 links that the last one has sublinks .
after click on the button menu get wider .
so far so good . i want to show sublinks with hover when mouse on the last links .
and also i want to show sublinks below the parent link with **click** when menu get wider .

i did this , but there is a problem . i want to show sublinks with click when menu get wide .
but now it didn't ?

**Here is my important Css**

```
.rightbar.noneStyle #rightMenu.accordion:hover .accordion-body.collapse{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    display: none;
    height:0;
    position:unset;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    visibility: visible;
}

.rightbar #rightMenu.accordion:hover .accordion-body.collapse {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    display: block;
    height: auto !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 61px;
    top: -8px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: maybe you can use ng-mouseleave !

Answer (score 0):

I've not used AngularJS just used simple jQuery and updated the markup. This is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0swx1y8f/1/).

```
$(function(){
    $('.dropdown.nonactive').click(function(){        $(this).toggleClass('nonactive').toggleClass('clicked');
    $('ul',this).slideToggle();
    });
});
```